# django how to make a proper authentication using google and facebook?

Tags: python, django, authentication, facebook-authentication, google-authentication

I'm starting for the first time to use in my project the facebook and google api to authenticate on my application.

I've seen a lot of librairies on the internet but I don't really know where to watch.

Is there a good and popular one to use? Or do Google and Facebook provide official one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably look into [python-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth).

It's a great framework to start with, and you'll probably find it's [documentation](http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/configuration/django.html) quite useful.

There's also an [example](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/tree/master/social/apps/django_app) in the repository.

However, if you'd like something that supports local registration, besides the Facebook / Google auth, then maybe [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) might be a better fit.

Comment: Make this answer a comment or http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers